# How to run rio-color from rasterio?

Tags: python, mapbox, numpy, rasterio, rio

I am completely new to GitHub, I've never had a need to use it, but now I would like to use [rio-color plugin](https://github.com/mapbox/rio-color) from rasterio, mapbox. I am on Ubuntu.

I've already managed to start using rasterio, load my tiffs and so on, but now I am stacked on installing rio-color.

How should I install it?

Should I download all directories and run setup.py or is there something I am missing?

Comment: If `pip` is installed on your system you can simply run `pip install rio-color` from the command line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @LoïcDutrieux for pointing out in the comments that you can use `pip` to install the plugin. A quick search indicates the plugin does exist in PyPI:

```
$ pip search rio-color

rio-color (0.4.0)                - Color correction plugin for rasterio
```

To install, use:

```
pip install rio-color
```

If you are running Windows, `pip` is installed by default with Python 3.4+. Otherwise, if you run Python 2.7, install [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), which also installs `pip`.